# ZF2 - duplication of functions in controllers

Tags: zend-framework2

i have got the same function in two Controllers in the another Module.
What i should do to not duplicate the same code?
Example
LoginController.php, and UserController.php

```
   public function getSessionStorage()
   {
        if (! $this->storage) {
            $this->storage = $this->getServiceLocator()
                                  ->get('Users\Model\MyAuthStorage');
        }

        return $this->storage;
    }
```

thanks for answer

Comment: Put in a base class and have your other classes derive from it. In case of controllers, most people do tend to eventually end up with base controllers.

Comment: All controllers extends AbstractActionController, so i should do something like BaseController and then extend by BaseController?

Comment: Yes. `YourBaseController extends AbstractActionController` and concrete controllers `extends YourBaseController`. However, if you're creating base controller for the sole purpose of acquiring an instance of `storage`, you may opt for a static utility instead.

Comment: As an alternative to the suggestions in the comments, controller plugins can provide common functionality across controllers without creating dependencies on base classes or static util functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to use Dependency Injection instead of proposed base controller.

It is very easy since ControllerManager in zf2 is a specialized version of ServiceManager. That means you can replace invokable in your config with factory for your controller, as in any other case of service manager, and inject your dependencies from there.

If you need examples, look at this repo https://github.com/GeeH/bad-puppy
Use github compare feature between `excercise/*` branches.